# Datatool, UTF8 and Export to a file

Tags: unicode, datatool

The title contains the problem: I have a `datatool` table, which contain accented characters (öäü) and I want to export the table into a CSV file :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
\DTLnewdb{table}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{name}{aouäöü}


\DTLdisplaydb{table}
\DTLsavedb{table}{export.csv}

\end{document}
```

With the package `inputenc`, the display of the table is ok:

```
name
aouäöü
```

But in the created file `export.csv` there is :

```
name
aou\IeC {\"a}\IeC {\"o}\IeC {\"u}
```

The best for me would be if the exported file was UTF8 encoded (instead of Ascii), and if it contained `aouäöü`. 
A second class solution which I could accept, would be, if the exported file contained

```
aou\"a\"o\"u
```

I could also accept a macro `\convert` which would take `öäü` as argument and would return `\"a\"o\"u`, but I don't know if it exists.

Comment: Just to note, this works out of box in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: ok. I have to admit, i don't know them. I use texlive. What would i have to do in order to use them ? A complete installation of a new latex distribution ? Would i have to change something in all my old .tex documents ?

Comment: TeX Live already has them. Search this website for `xetex` and `luatex`. Amongst other stuff you will find information on how to migrate from pdfTeX.

Comment: these are replacements of the pdflatex command, do i understand correctly ?

Comment: pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX are TeX _engines_, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex` is how you invoke these engines with the LaTeX _format_.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the `\"a` version by redefining `\IeC`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
\DTLnewdb{table}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{name}{aouäöü}


\DTLdisplaydb{table}
\def\IeC#1{#1}
\DTLsavedb{table}{export.csv}

\end{document}
```

For real UTF8 you could try something like this: Complete (!) (the first entry is 128, the last 255, the second argument contains the number in hex) and then save this as `identity.def`:

```
\ProvidesFile{identity.def}
   [2012/02/23 v1.0 Input encoding file]
\makeatletter
\DeclareInputText{128}{\string^^80}
%....
\DeclareInputText{164}{\string^^a4}
%....
\DeclareInputText{182}{\string^^b6}
%....
\DeclareInputText{188}{\string^^bc}
%....
\DeclareInputText{195}{\string^^c3}
% ...
\DeclareInputText{228}{\string^^e4}
%...
\DeclareInputText{246}{\string^^f6}
%...
\DeclareInputText{252}{\string^^fc}
%...
\makeatother
\endinput
```

Then this (I hope without side-effects ;-)) should give you UTF8 export (if the main document is UTF8 encoded. If it is in e.g. ansinew, the export will be ansinew too):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
\DTLnewdb{table}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{name}{aouäöü}


\DTLdisplaydb{table}

{\inputencoding{identity}
\DTLsavedb{table}{export.csv}
}

öäü
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A patch that *might* accomplish the `\"a` version is

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\DTLsavedb}
  {\protected@write\@dtl@write{}{\@dtl@row}}
  {{\let\IeC\@firstofone\protected@write\@dtl@write{}{\@dtl@row}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

but this can fail for other accented characters. The problem is in how `\@dtl@row` is defined (with `\protected@edef`) and the implementation of UTF-8 support in LaTeX that guarantees correct writes as far as LaTeX is concerned, but is not what one can expect for other purposes like yours.

EDIT: Expanding on Ulrike's idea, here's a version that should be safe.

This code should go in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DTLsavedbutf}[2]{%
  \begingroup\count@=127
  \loop\ifnum\count@<\@cclv
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \begingroup\lccode`!=\count@
    \lowercase{\endgroup
      \expandafter\DeclareInputText\expandafter{\number\count@}{\string!}}
  \repeat
  \DTLsavedb{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

and then the command `\DTLsavedbutf` will write all characters (with high bit set) without any special interpretation.

If you want to apply this to *every* `\DTLsavedb` command, then the code should redefine this command:

```
\makeatletter
\let\original@DTLsavedb\DTLsavedb
\renewcommand{\DTLsavedb}[2]{%
  \begingroup\count@=127
  \loop\ifnum\count@<\@cclv
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \begingroup\lccode`!=\count@
    \lowercase{\endgroup
      \expandafter\DeclareInputText\expandafter{\number\count@}{\string!}}
  \repeat
  \original@DTLsavedb{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

In this way you can use `\DTLsavedb` and not a separate command.

Comment: thanks for the patch. By the way, is `datatool` the only one (or at least the canonical one) package, that allows one to store and read values from tables ?

Comment: yes ... it seems to work ... but it's almost black magic for me ! :)

Comment: why couldn t we put the whole code (without the `\DTLsavedb{#1}{#2}` in a separate command and then call the usual `\DTLsavedb{table}{file.csv}` ? because it could cause side effects on the rest of the document ?

Comment: well i meant : what is against defining a command which only does all the `\DeclareInputText`, and using the original `DTLsavedb` ?

Comment: You have to do those `\DeclareInputText` only for that specific purpose, otherwise printing UTF-8 characters in the file would be disabled. So enclosing the call of `\DTLsavedb` in a group is necessary.

Comment: Is there any reason one wants to write the 7 bit characters _with_ special interpretations? Some of them get substituted as well (like `"`, which becomes `\csqQQ`). In a quick test I let the counter start at 1 instead of 127, which seems to fix this, but I am not so sure about the implications.

Comment: @Daniel I don't think the 7 bit characters have special interpretation; but perhaps you have `babel` loaded and this might interfere.

Comment: Right, found it: Its `csquotes` with a `MakeOuterQuote{"}`. Anyway, is it a bad idea to write the 7 bit characters also "literally"?

Comment: @Daniel I think it might be a good idea to look for the characters activated by `babel` or other packages.